# How do determine LIVE vs UAT environment

Tags: java

Currently in my app I'm using this in a jsp to determine my environment

```
<% String environment = (request.getRequestURL().indexOf("localhost") > 0) ? "dev" : "uat"; %>
<% request.setAttribute("environment", environment); %>
<% if (!environment.equals("live")) { %>
```

I'd really like to change that so that it's a server-specific setting because there are a few other places where I need to run this same check.  Is it possible for me to set a variable on my UAT server to `UAT` and then the absense of that variable on dev means that we're in dev?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a VM argument for the environment.

```
-Druntime.env=uat or dev or tst or ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, can you elaborate?